# InvalidArgumentError: Graph Execution Error - indices[31,66] = -1 is not in [0, 3345)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

The error output:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 5>()
      3 cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
      4 print(X_train)
----> 5 cnn.fit(X_train, y_train)
...
Node: 'model/embedding/embedding_lookup'
indices[31,66] = -1 is not in [0, 3345)
     [[{{node model/embedding/embedding_lookup}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1090]
```

I am trying to make a text classification CNN, so X_train contains feature vectors of words in range of -1 to 1 (after using MinMaxScaler), and y_train are numeric labels.

The model summary are as follows:

```
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_3 (InputLayer)           [(None, None)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 embedding_2 (Embedding)        (None, None, 128)    428160      ['input_3[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_6 (Conv1D)              (None, None, 16)     6160        ['embedding_2[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_7 (Conv1D)              (None, None, 16)     10256       ['embedding_2[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_8 (Conv1D)              (None, None, 16)     14352       ['embedding_2[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 global_max_pooling1d_6 (Global  (None, 16)          0           ['conv1d_6[0][0]']               
 MaxPooling1D)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 global_max_pooling1d_7 (Global  (None, 16)          0           ['conv1d_7[0][0]']               
 MaxPooling1D)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 global_max_pooling1d_8 (Global  (None, 16)          0           ['conv1d_8[0][0]']               
 MaxPooling1D)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 tf.concat_2 (TFOpLambda)       (None, 48)           0           ['global_max_pooling1d_6[0][0]', 
                                                                  'global_max_pooling1d_7[0][0]', 
                                                                  'global_max_pooling1d_8[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 dense_2 (Dense)                (None, 6)            294         ['tf.concat_2[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 459,222
Trainable params: 459,222
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Where could the error be stemming from?

Thank you!

Comment: You have an `Embedding` layer - it needs positive integers as inputs (for each word a different single number). It outputs learned feature vectors for these words

Comment: Correct, Embedding does not take word vectors as input.

Comment: I see, how should I change it to fit my CNN? Thank you for the replies! @AndrzejO